# Select only Duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

On Top is a sample database. I need a query to display

1. Filter the customers who have made more than one project ongoing at a time.
2. Delete the records of any customers who have no ongoing project currently (Record of past projects should be deleted).

Please help

```
GROUP BY CustomerID
Having COUNT(*) >= 1 is not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For duplicates there're different technics, for example, you can use window function:

```
;with cte as (
    select *, count(*) over(partition by customerID) as cnt
    from <Table>
)
select *
from cte
where
    cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only the most recent project, use `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
     select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by customerid order by enddate desc) as seqnum
     from table t
    )
select t.*
from t
where seqnum > 1;
```

To actually delete the older records from the database, you can use a similar construct:

```
with todelete as (
     select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by customerid order by enddate desc) as seqnum
     from table t
    )
delete from todelete
where seqnum = 1;
```

However, if you just want the customers with no ongoing proejct:

```
select customerid
from table t
group by customerid
having sum(case when getdate() between startdate and endate then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: You have a typo in the second query. Should be `delete from todelete
where seqnum > 1`

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the code set.about the delete code how can we specify a date? Ex: Delete projects which are older than a specified date.

Comment: @ShazminA . . . You would just use a `where` clause.